# Delete element of Solr

Tags: json, solr

I deleted an item you do not need to solr,  but I solr response still appears.

**The json:**

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 1,
        "params": {
            "facet": "true",
            "q": "*:*",
            "facet.limit": "-1",
            "facet.field": "manufacturer",
            "wt": "json",
            "rows": "0"
        }
    },
    "response": {
        "numFound": 84,
        "start": 0,
        "docs": []
    },
    "facet_counts": {
        "facet_queries": {},
        "facet_fields": {
            "manufacturer": [
                "Chevrolet",
                0,
                "abarth",
                1,
                "audi",
                7,
                "austin",
                1,
                "bmw",
                2,
                "daewoo",
                2,
                "ford",
                1,
                "fso",
                1,
                "honda",
                1,
                "hyundai",
                1,
                "jaguar",
                3,
                "lexus",
                1,
                "mazda",
                1,
                "mitsubishi",
                1,
                "nissan",
                1,
                "pontiac",
                1,
                "seat",
                1
            ]
        },
        "facet_dates": {},
        "facet_ranges": {}
    }
}
```

the deleted item is "chevrolet", now this to '0 'but it still appears.

```
"manufacturer":["Chevrolet",0,
```

I wish I could delete the item completely, is that possible.. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a two step approach I would follow:

- Make sure changes(deletion) is committed. You may issue a commit
- If it still shows facets with zero count, you may append **&facet.mincount=1** to your query

**&facet.mincount=1** will make sure facets with zero count do not show up.

For more details, please refer to: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.mincount

Answer (score 1):

In your case probably it is because of **uninverted index** created by solr.
Pass **facet.mincount=1** in your query to get rid of this problem.